# Adding two vectors using operator overloading

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I got a class `Vectors` which has private dynamic array.
All I wanted to do is to add two `Vectors` objects like A = A + B, but the program keeps crashing.

This is declaration of my class:

```
class Vectors
    {
    private:
        int* vector;
    public:
        Vectors(int);
        Vectors(Vectors&);
        ~Vectors();

        Vectors operator+(Vectors&);

    };
```

This is my implementation:

```
#include "Vectors.h"
#include "iostream"
using namespace std;

Vectors::Vectors(int value)
{
    this->vector = new int[3];
    for (auto i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        vector[i] = 3;
    }
}

Vectors::Vectors(Vectorsy& copy)
{
    this->vector = new int[3];
    for (auto i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        vector[i] = copy.vector[i];
    }
}

Vectors::~Vectors()
{
    delete[] vector;
}

Vectors Vectors::operator+(Vectors& obj) // There is sth wrong here.
{
    for (auto i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        this->vector[i] += obj.vector[i];

    return *this;
}
```

This is the error I get:

[image]

Comment: Make sure to include the error your compiler is giving you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you need an `operator=` function.  You haven't implemented it so the compiler writes a default one which does the wrong thing (due to the fact that the class has a pointer).  Most likely the crash is occurring while deleting the same memory twice.

See [What is The Rule of Three?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three)

Comment: You are damn right, cheers. When I creating new object this way Vectors C = Vectors(A+B); everything is right.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the copy Constructor (Vectors::Vectors(const Vectors& copy)
Hear a working code.

```
#include "iostream"
using namespace std;

class Vectors
    {
    private:
        int* vector;
    public:
        Vectors(int);
        Vectors(const Vectors&);
        ~Vectors();

        Vectors operator+(Vectors&);

    };


Vectors::Vectors(int value)
{
    this->vector = new int[3];
    for (auto i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        vector[i] = 3;
    }
}

Vectors::Vectors(const Vectors& copy)
{
    this->vector = new int[3];
    for (auto i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        vector[i] = copy.vector[i];
    }
}

Vectors::~Vectors()
{
    delete[] vector;
}

Vectors Vectors::operator+(Vectors& obj) // There is sth wrong here.
{
    for (auto i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        this->vector[i] += obj.vector[i];

    return *this;
}

int main()
{
        Vectors A(3), B(3);
        Vectors C = A+B;
}
```

Comment: Try Vectors A(0), B(3); and then A = B + B; not working

Comment: because operator= not defined

Comment: but you are right copy condtructor was only one bug